# Perl match only returning "1". Booleans? Why?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

This has got to be obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

I have a documents containing thousands of records just like below:

```
Row:1 DATA:
[0]37755442
[1]DDG00000010
[2]FALLS
[3]IMAGE
[4]Defect
[5]3
[6]CLOSED
```

I've managed to get each record separated and I'm now trying to parse out each field.

I'm trying to match the numbered headers so that I can pull out the data that succeeds them but the problem is that my matches are only returning me "1" when they succeed and nothing if they don't.  This is happening for any match I try to apply.

For instance, applied to a simple word within each record:

```
my($foo) = $record=~ /Defect/;
print STDOUT $foo;
```

prints out out a "1" for each record if it contains "Defect" and nothing if it contains something else.

Alternatively:

```
$record =~ /Defect/;
print STDOUT $1;
```

prints absolutely nothing.

```
$record =~ s/Defect/Blefect/
```

will replace "Defect" with "Blefect" perfectly fine on the other hand.

I'm really confused as to why the returns on my matches are so screwy.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be in `$foo` after matched?

Comment: Many people have given you the answer to the regex question, but I think you are asking in a bit of an XY problem. `I'm trying to match the numbered headers so that I can pull out the data that succeeds them`: what do you want you final data structure to look like? Most likely it can be accomplished more quickly than looping and regexing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use capturing parentheses to actually capture:

```
if ($record =~ /(Defect)/ ) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  That did it.  I scoured and scoured and never once did I
run across capturing parentheses.  I must be blind.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you really want is to wrap the regex in parentheses:

```
my($foo) = $record=~ /(Defect)/;
```

In list context, the groups are returned, not the match itself. And your original code has no groups.

Comment: This was very helpful - thanks. I had forgotten the binding operator's different behavior in scalar/list context.

Answer (score 4):

The `=~` perl operator takes a string (left operand) and a regular expression (right operand) and matches the string against the RE, returning a boolean value (true or false) depending on whether the re matches.

Now perl doesn't really have a boolean type -- instead every value (of any type) is treated as either 'true' or 'false' when in a boolean context -- most things are 'true', but the empty string and the special 'undef' value for undefined things are false.  So when returning a boolean, it generall uses '1' for true and '' (empty string) for false.

Now as to your last question, where trying to print `$1` prints nothing.  Whenever you match a regular expression, perl sets `$1`, `$2` ... to the values of parenthesized subexpressions withing the RE.  In your example however, there are NO parenthesized sub expressions, so $1 is always empty.  If you change it to

```
$record =~ /(Defect)/;
print STDOUT $1;
```

You'll get something more like what you expect (`Defect` if it matches and nothing if it doesn't).

The most common idiom for regexp matching I generally see is something like:

```
if ($string =~ /regexp with () subexpressions/) {
    ... code that uses $1 etc for the subexpressions matched
} else {
    ... code for when the expression doesn't match at all
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [perlop, Quote and Quote-Like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) [bits in brackets added by me]:

> /PATTERN/msixpodualgc
>
> Searches a string for a pattern match, and **in scalar context returns true [1] if it succeeds, false [undef] if it fails.**

(Looking at the section on `s///` will also be useful ;-)

Perl just *doesn't have* a discreet boolean type or `true`/`false` aliases so `1` and `undef` are often used: however, it could very well *could be other values* without making the documentation incorrect.

`$1` will never be defined because there is no capture group: perhaps [`$&` (aka `$MATCH`)](http://p3rl.org/var#%24MATCH) is desired? (Or better, change the regular expression to have a capture group ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

Isn't it supposed to return a list of the matches themselves in list context though?

    @foo = ($bug =~ /Defect/);
    print STDOUT @foo;

or

    print STDOUT @foo[0];

will give me the exact same thing.

Comment: @ManAnimal Add a capture group and compare. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my($foo) = $record=~ /Defect/;
print STDOUT $foo;
```

Rather than this you should do

```
$record =~ /Defect/;
my $foo = $&; # Matched portion of the $record.
```

As your goal seems to be to get the matched portion.
The return value is true/false indicating if match was successful or not.

You may find http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of a match as "true" or "false", then do the pattern match in scalar context. That's what you did in your first example. You performed a pattern match and assigned the result to the scalar my($foo). So $foo got a "true" or "false" value.

But if you want to capture the text that matched a part of your pattern, use grouping parentheses and then check the corresponding $ variable. For example, consider the expression:

```
$record =~ /(.*)ing/
```

A match on the word "speaking" will assign "speak" to $1, "listening" will assign "listen" to $1, etc. That's what you are trying to do in your second example. The trouble is that you need to add in the grouping parentheses. "$record =~ /Defect/" will assign nothing to $1 because there are no grouping parentheses in the pattern.