# Why does regex capturing group not return the captured text when assigned to scalar variable?

Tags: regex, perl, capturing-group

I want to capture a number contained in certain lines of a file.  I am using Perl and I am using a matching operator to capture the number occurring at a specific position relative to other symbols in the lines of the file.  Here is an example line:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=3000306 step=1
```

Here is the relevant portion of the script:

```
while ( <FILE> ) {
        if ( $_=~m/fixedStep/ ) {
             my $line = $_;
             print $line;
             my $position = ($line =~ /start\=(\d+)/);

             print "position is $position\n\n";

}
```

`$position` prints as `1`, not the number I need.  According the online regex tool regex101.com, the regex I am using works; it captures the appropriate element in the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl match only returning "1". Booleans? Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855637/perl-match-only-returning-1-booleans-why)

Comment: Not sure why can't you just use a single test `(/fixedStep.*?start=(\d+)/)`, then work with `$1` alone.

Comment: The left hand side of the assignment operator controls the *context*. The match returns different things in different contexts: success in scalar context, captured groups in list context.

Comment: It's not necessary to specify `$_` when matching against it.  You can just say `if ( /fixedStep/ ) {` on the 2nd line.

Comment: @user1937198 That is not a duplicate, in this question there *are* capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

To get the capture groups from a match, you have to call it in list *context*. It can be turned on by enclosing the scalar on the left hand side of the assignment operator into parentheses:

```
my ($position) = $line =~ /start=(\d+)/;
```

Note that `=` is not special in regexes, so no need to backslash it. Also be careful with `\d` if your input is unicode - you probably do not want to match non-arabic [digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit) (as 四 or ௫).

Answer (score 4):

When you use `my $position = ($line =~ /start\=(\d+)/);`, you are evaluating the match in scalar context, because of the scalar assignment on the LHS. In scalar context, you are going to get the size of the list produced by the matching operation in `$position`, which will be either `0` or `1` depending on whether this particular match succeeded.

By using `my ($position) =` on the LHS, you create list context. [The successful matched substring ends up in `$position`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Extracting-matches) (if there are more, they get discarded).

Also, *in general*, avoid bareword filehandles such as `FILE` (except for special builtin ones such as `DATA` and `ARGV`). Those are package level variables. Also, assign to a lexical variable in the smallest possible scope, instead of overwriting `$_`. In addition, the test and match can be combined, resulting in a more specific specification of the string you want to match. Of course, you know the constraints best, so, for example, if the `chrom` field always appears second in valid input, you should specify that.

The pattern below just requires that the lines begin with `fixedStep` and there is one more field before the one you want to capture.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if (my ($position) = ($line =~ m{
        \A
        fixedStep
        \s+ \S+ \s+
        start=([0-9]+)
    }x)) {
        print "$position\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=0 step=1
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=3000306 step=1
start=9999 -- hey, that's wrong
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> tt
0
3000306
```

Answer (score 1):

[ EDIT: See comments for explanation about why struck text is wrong ]

You can use

```
my ($position) = ($line =~ /start\=(\d+)/);
```

<del>or</del>

<del>`my $position = $line =~ /start\=(\d+)/;`</del>

either should work

Otherwise, <del>you are mixing list and scalar contexts</del>, and <del>subsequently just getting the length of the list</del>

Comment: what are the `()` doing in each case?  why are they important?  does it have something to do with list context?  I also tried to use `@position` instead of `$position`, and that worked as well.  why?

Comment: Yes, it does. Check the (almost similar) question mentioned in the comments.

Comment: 'just getting the length of the list' - that's not correct for `m//` operator: *'...and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails'*

Comment: thanks @raina77ow and choroba.

leaving errors as is for educational reasons

Comment: `( ... )` doesn't create a list; it just overrides precedence.