# Log file parsing with Perl

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'tagged.txt';
open(my $info, '<', 'tagged.txt') or die $!;

while(my $line = <$info>){
    if ($line =~ /someString/){
        #
    } else if ($line =~ /someOtherString/){
        #
    }
    #...
}

close $info
```

So I'm trying to parse some wild log files into a well formatted .csv file. I want to look through the logfile line by line and check if one of my desired values / strings appear in that line. Let's say we have something like this:

```
Aug 27 13:59:36 topas user.info POS[548]: 00:11:33.989304 <GPS> Input To Sensor Fusion - f64Longitude (deg) = 13286667
```

One of the values I'm interested in is for example the f64Longitude (deg), respectively the value that appears **behind** "f64Longitude (deg) = ".
My question is now: how do I access the string that is located **after** some regEx that I've found...

Comment: Your question is not very clear, post proper input data and output what are you expecting.

Comment: $1 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855637/perl-match-only-returning-1-booleans-why    You may need to expand your search to include the portion after the f64...   You should consider yourself lucky if that is always the terminating portion before \n

Comment: This may be tangential, but you r'else if' shou'd be 'elsif'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the token you are looking for and use regex groups to retrieve matching part. For example:

```
my $str = 'Aug 27 13:59:36 topas user.info POS[548]: 00:11:33.989304 <GPS> Input To Sensor Fusion - f64Longitude (deg) = 13286667';
if ($str =~ /f64Longitude \(deg\) = (\d+)/) {
    print $1;
}

#prints 13286667
```